# Box2D - FRIM (Frame Rate Independent Movement)

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d

I've been trying to implement a FRIM system for my game for the last couple of days.I did some research and came upon [this article](http://blog.allanbishop.com/box-2d-2-1a-tutorial-part-10-fixed-time-step/) - it seemed simple enough to implement so I got started.
Everything seems to work fine except I get some temporal aliasing (moving bodies seem to jump ahead a bit) - this happens when more Box2D steps are processed....I think.

```
private  const FIXED_TIMESTEP:Number = 1 / 60;
private  const velocityIterations:int = 8;
private  const positionIterations:int = 3;
private  var fixedTimestepAccumulator:Number = 0;
private  var fixedTimestepAccumulatorRatio:Number = 0;

public function Step(dt:Number):void
{
  //dt - time between frames - I'm passing the e.passedTime - from the enter frame event; using Starling

   fixedTimestepAccumulator += dt;
   var nSteps:uint = Math.floor(fixedTimestepAccumulator / FIXED_TIMESTEP);

   if (nSteps > 0)
   {
      fixedTimestepAccumulator  = fixedTimestepAccumulator - nSteps * FIXED_TIMESTEP;
    }

    fixedTimestepAccumulatorRatio = fixedTimestepAccumulator / FIXED_TIMESTEP;

    var nStepsClamped:int = Math.min(nSteps, MAX_STEPS);

            for (var i:int = 0; i < nStepsClamped; ++i)
            {
                    resetSmoothStates();
                    singleStep(FIXED_TIMESTEP);     

            }

            world.ClearForces();
            smoothStates(); 

}

private  function resetSmoothStates():void
{       

     for (var bb:b2Body = world.GetBodyList(); bb; bb = bb.GetNext())
    {

    if (bb.GetUserData() is MyUserData && bb.GetType() != b2Body.b2_staticBody  )
    {
                 //each of my bodies have a reference to their sprite (actor) in userData
        var _userdata:MyUserData=bb.GetUserData();
        _userdata.x =  _userdata.bodyPreviousX  =  bb.GetPosition().x * RATIO;
        _userdata.y= _userdata.bodyPreviousY =   - bb.GetPosition().y* RATIO;
        _userdata.rotation = _userdata.bodypreviousRotation=  _userdata.bodypreviousRotation =  - bb.GetAngle();

    }
   }

}

private function smoothStates():void
{

    var oneMinusRatio:Number = 1.0  - fixedTimestepAccumulatorRatio;

    for (var bb:b2Body = world.GetBodyList(); bb; bb = bb.GetNext())
    {

      if (bb.GetUserData() is MyUserData && bb.GetType() != b2Body.b2_staticBody  )
       {

    var userdata=bb.GetUserData();
    userdata.x =  (fixedTimestepAccumulatorRatio *  bb.GetPosition().x * RATIO + oneMinusRatio * userdata.bodyPreviousX)  ;
    userdata.y =   (- fixedTimestepAccumulatorRatio * bb.GetPosition().y * RATIO    + oneMinusRatio  * userdata.bodyPreviousY) ;
    userdata.rotation =  (- fixedTimestepAccumulatorRatio * bb.GetAngle() + oneMinusRatio * userdata.bodypreviousRotation);

     }
     }                      

}

private  function singleStep(dt:Number):void
{
    Input();
    world.Step(dt, velocityIterations, positionIterations);

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any help, suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with another approach. I'm using filtered delta times for the physics (I know this can cause some problems).
Here's what I'm doing now:

```
//Play around with this filter value if things don't look right
var filter:Number=0.4;
filtered_dt= time_between_frames * filter + filtered_dt * (1 - filter);

//Poll imputs and apply forces

// I use velocityIterations =6, positionIterations=3
world.Step(filtered_dt, velocityIterations, positionIterations);

//move sprites here

 world.ClearForces();
```

Another thing you have to do is to scale the forces you apply to your bodies using filtered_dt so things don't "explode" when the frame rate changes a lot.

Hope this helps some one else ... it's not the perfect solution but it works for me.
If you have slow moving bodies the interpolation method above should work fine too.

Answer (score 0):

I did this once in a game I was working on so that I could lockstep the game to a certain update rate (this was in iOS).  This was based on the code in Daley's book (Learning iOS Game Programming), which was based on some other article in the web (I believe, it may be Allen Bishop's).  The code looked like this:

```
void GameManager::UpdateGame()
{
   const uint32 MAXIMUM_FRAME_RATE = Constants::DEFAULT_OBJECT_CYCLES_PER_SECOND();
   const uint32 MINIMUM_FRAME_RATE = 10;
   const uint32 MAXIMUM_CYCLES_PER_FRAME = (MAXIMUM_FRAME_RATE/MINIMUM_FRAME_RATE);
   const double UPDATE_INTERVAL = (1.0/MAXIMUM_FRAME_RATE);

   static double lastFrameTime = 0.0;
   static double cyclesLeftOver = 0.0;

   double currentTime;
   double updateIterations;

   currentTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
   updateIterations = ((currentTime - lastFrameTime) + cyclesLeftOver);

   if(updateIterations > (MAXIMUM_CYCLES_PER_FRAME*UPDATE_INTERVAL))
   {
      updateIterations = MAXIMUM_CYCLES_PER_FRAME*UPDATE_INTERVAL;
   }

   while (updateIterations >= UPDATE_INTERVAL)
   {
      //      DebugLogCPP("Frame Running");
      updateIterations -= UPDATE_INTERVAL;
      // Set the random seed for this cycle.
      RanNumGen::SetSeed(_cycleManager->GetObjectCycle());
      // Dispatch messages.
      _messageManager->SendMessages();
      // Update all entities.
      _entityManager->Update();
      // Update the physics
      _gameWorldManager->Update(Constants::DEFAULT_OBJECT_CYCLE_SECONDS());
      // Advance the cycle clock.
      _cycleManager->Update();
   }

   cyclesLeftOver = updateIterations;
   lastFrameTime = currentTime;
}
```

I can't put my finger on the specific item that is *wrong* in yours.  However, this part is suspicious:

var nStepsClamped:int = Math.min(nSteps, MAX_STEPS);

Before this, you updated your accumulator with:

fixedTimestepAccumulator  = fixedTimestepAccumulator - nSteps * FIXED_TIMESTEP;

But now the actual number of steps you are going to execute may be different because of the clamping (nStepsClamped).  So your time accumulation is different than the number of steps you actually execute.

Was this helpful?

Comment: I only step(update) the physics using a fixed time step (FIXED_TIMESTEP) .... so nSteps  is how many steps I can fit in the time that has accumulated.... nStepsClamped is just a limit so that things don't spiral out of control when the frame rate drops (only a maximum of 5 physics steps are taken).

Comment: My problem is most likely with the interpolation of the sprite positions ... but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Hmmm...typically in Box2D, the positions of the sprites are set with something like:  Vec2 bodyPos = body.GetPosition(); Vec2 spritePos(bodyPos.x*PTMRatio,bodyPos.y*PTMRatio).  PTMRatio is usually 32 or variable (see http://nonlinearideas.com/viewports/), but not 1:1 per the manual.  It's odd that this would be causing a jump unless it is wrapping...

Comment: If nSteps is big, say 10, then you subtract that from your accumulator.  Then you clamp it to 5 and use that for the number of steps.  Your accumulator may be negative at that point, so it takes a while for it to catch up and give you nSteps > 0.  So your execution of the physics "hiccups".  Maybe...what values are coming out of your nSteps calculation during each update cycle?